# Scala Map Reduction and Aggregation

Tags: scala

I have a Map that looks like this and is of Type Map[String, Seq[String]]

```
Map(
 "5" -> Seq("5.1"),
 "5.1" -> Seq("5.1.1", "5.1.2"),
 "5.1.1" -> Seq("5.1.1.1"),
 "5.1.2" -> Seq.empty[String],
 "5.1.1.1" -> Seq.empty[String]
)
```

Given a key, I would like to fetch all the values recursively that belongs to the given key. Say for example., if I want to look up for the key 5, I expect the result to be:

```
Given Input is: 5
Expected Output is: Seq(5.1, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.1.1)
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
def fetchSequence(inputId: String, acc: Seq[String], seqMap: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Seq[String] = seqMap.get(inputId) match {
  case None => acc
  case Some(subSeq) =>
    val newAcc = acc ++ subSeq
    subSeq.collect {
      case subId=> fetchSequence(subId, newAcc, seqMap)
    }.flatten
}
```

I get an empty result when I call fetchSequence with the Map that I have above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhat more concise :

```
def recGet[A](map: Map[A, Seq[A]])(key: A): Seq[A] = 
  map.get(key).fold(
    // return empty Seq if key not found
    Seq.empty[A])(
    // return a Seq with 
    //   the key and 
    //   the result of recGet called recursively 
    //      (for all the elements in the Seq[A] found for key)
    x => Seq(key) ++ x.flatMap(recGet(map)))
```

You can use `recGet` as :

```
val sections = Map(
  "5" -> Seq("5.1"),
  "5.1" -> Seq("5.1.1", "5.1.2"),
  "5.1.1" -> Seq("5.1.1.1"),
  "5.1.2" -> Seq.empty[String],
  "5.1.1.1" -> Seq.empty[String]
)

recGet(sections)("5")      // Seq[String] = List(5, 5.1, 5.1.1, 5.1.1.1, 5.1.2)
recGet(sections)("5.1.1")  // Seq[String] = List(5.1.1, 5.1.1.1)
recGet(sections)("5.2")    // Seq[String] = List()
```

This will also give you the (first) element itself (if it exists in the map), if you don't want that, you can probably wrap `recGet` in another method which uses `drop(1)` on the result of `recGet`.

Comment: This is fantastic! I am guessing it would loop infinitely on recursive keys (eg `"5" -> Seq("5.1", "5")`) ?

Comment: @evan058 Indeed, if that's the case you need to be able to inspect the current "result", which is impossible with something recursive like this.

Comment: Cool! I guess I will not have situations where I have keys like "5" -> Seq("5.1", "5")

Comment: @Peter: would you mind taking a look at a similar probmem here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143191/scala-recursive-reduction